# How can I add values to a specific list within a dictionary?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
Student = {'Name': 'John Robert, 
          'Age': 22, 
          'Courses': ["SQL", "Math", 'Computer Science'],
          'Grade': [76, 82, 69, 98], 
          'Phone': '555-555', 'ID': 54321}
```

How can I add values in the list call Grade without doing it manually?

Comment: Not really sure what "without doing it manually" means.

Comment: I meant adding the value inside the list instead of using a function/method to  add it.

Comment: Note the following: the fact that your list is an element of a dictionary is not relevant. Your solution is just how items are "added" (appended...!) to lists in python. Also, you appended 86 manually.

Answer (score 1):

I just figure it out a minute after writing this post.

Here is my solution for anyone interested:

```
Student['Grade'].append(86)

print(Student['Grade'])
```

After printing, I saw the value `86` was added to the list.